# Trigger Not Preventing Invalid Insert (Possible incorrect select statement)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, triggers

I am attempting to use a trigger to prevent an insert when the table reaches a certain number of values

my trigger is the following

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER validate_insert /*create trigger to validate updates */
BEFORE INSERT ON trainer_party_members 
FOR EACH ROW

SET @trainernumber=NULL;

SELECT COUNT(trainer_party_members.trainer_id) INTO @trainernumber FROM trainer_party_members WHERE trainer_party_members.trainer_id=trainer_id;


IF (@trainernumber=6) THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "maximum amount of trainers";
END IF;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

it is supposed to stop inserts when reaches 6. i am not sure why it is not working

thought it may be a problem with my select statement

inserting into the trainer_party_memebers table looks like the following

```
INSERT INTO trainer_party_members (pokemon_id, trainer_id)
VALUES (1, 1), -- Trade this one (Will's Pikachu)
       (2, 1),
       (3, 1),
       (4, 1),
       (5, 1),
       (6, 1),
       (7, 1),
       (11, 2); -- for this one. (Koga's Squirtle)
```

theoretically it should prevent the (7,1) value from entering

Comment: *`WHERE trainer_party_members.trainer_id=trainer_id;`* What is (more precisely - should be) `trainer_id`? *theoretically it should prevent the (7,1) value from entering* Absolutely impossibe. Either all rows are inserted or an error occures (maybe generated by SIGNAL) and none rows are inserted.

Comment: trainer_id is the the trainer_id of the value being inserted

Comment: *trainer_id is the the trainer_id of the value being inserted* No. It is the same as `trainer_party_members.trainer_id`. For to refer to inserted value you must use alias `NEW`.

Comment: and how would i make it so that no rows are inserted?

Comment: the error prints but it doesnt prevent anything from happening. i instead made a new insert function that tried to add just one more value which would push the limit over the 6. the error printed out but it still allowed the inseet

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a189cb421e1227a988ca49b7fdec7ea